# נגעים of houses - is the house מקבל טומאה from the נגע, or are the נגע and the house together one object of טומאה

Tags: tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, lomdus, tzaraas-negaim, parashat-metzora

Is the house מקבל טומאה from the נגע, or are the נגע and the house together one 'item/חפצא' of טומאה?

Same question essentially by נגעי אדם and נגעי בגדים as well.

See Kisvei HaGrach siman 65. Please let me know if you have any other mareh mekomos on this or any other insight into this question, or any possible nafka minas.

Comment: Maybe a different way of phrasing your *chakirah*. Are the stones with the *tzaraas* the *mekor ha'tumah* for the rest of the house, or is all the house *nitmah* evenly from the *tzaraas* even though it occurs on only a few of the stones.